# Is there a way to add ApiControllerAttribute in a global manner in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Normally if the application serves as API purpose only, I want to save the efforts of manually decorating each controller with `[ApiController]`. How can I add this globally?

Comment: You need to make your own middleware in Startup.cs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from the ASP.NET Core 2.2 `[ApiController]` attribute can be used on an assembly

```cs
[assembly: ApiController]
namespace WebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        }
    }
}
```

Note that you must set compatibility version of 2.2 or later for this to work.

---

Another approach is just to use base controller and annotate it with the `[ApiController]` attribute

```cs
[ApiController]
public abstract class MyBaseController
{
}
```

[Annotation with ApiController attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#annotation-with-apicontroller-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6, finding the right place for this namespace attribute might not be obvious when using the new File-Scoped Namespaces in Program.cs.  One solution is to create another file (that gets automatically nested under Program.cs) called Program.Assembly.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[assembly: ApiController]
namespace HelloWorld.Api
{
    public class Program
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

But, you can always place it right in the main program file as well:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[assembly: ApiController]
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```